# Remove customer details from thank you page (order-received) on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization, hook-woocommerce

I'm new here and I'm studing how to make a little wp site with woocommerce.
I didn't find anything for my case in the other public questions. I need to remove customer details from thank you page (order-received) on woocommerce but not remove the order details.
I use woodmart themes and I tried to change some stuff on `thankyou.php` file in the `/wp-content/themes/woodmart/woocommerce/checkout` directory, but I could only remove all or nothing.
some one ca help me please?
thanks a lot.

Comment: _**"I tried to change some stuff".**_ It might be helpful to mention what you have adjusted

Comment: Ok, thanks. How can attach my thankyou.php file? to explain better what I tried to change..you can find my php on a page of my site: http://www.villaggioverde.org/agrinew/wp-admin/post.php?post=7863

Comment: I tried to cancel this part of code: 

<?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( woodmart_get_opt( ‘thank_you_page_default_content’ ) ) : ?>
<?php do_action( ‘woocommerce_thankyou_’ . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
<?php do_action( ‘woocommerce_thankyou’, $order->get_id() ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

but without nice result